# I want fix a pyttsx3 program

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx

I have recently install pyttsx3 and I use the code:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

But when I run this program, I have some problems: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUYzb.png)

I don't how to handle this :(

Comment: Please, don't use images here

Comment: It seems like you don't have a voice engine in that small program at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this program. I have had some experience with this.

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')<--- Sapi5 is Win 10 only. Find the one for your system.
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Then this is what you do for it to speak:

```
speak("I am speaking this right now")
```